# document.getElementById is not working on Javascript's external file

Tags: javascript

Obviously I am a novice in JavaScript and this is what I need to unlock its universe for me;

I have and HTML code;

```
<p id = "changetext"> Unlock the universe of JavaScript </p>
```

If I use the inline script, it works fine to change the innerHTML of

tag - 
    
        document.getElementById('changetext').innerHTML = "Welcome HOME!";

But if I move document.getElementById('changetext').innerHTML = "Welcome HOME!"; to external JavaScript file that is correctly linked in my HTML page, it doesn't work. Even all my functions are not working from the external file. The only thing that works is the alert command, like alert("Here we are!");

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Did you see any errors in the console? Also, please post the rest of your code.

Comment: Where are you calling your function?

Comment: call your function after the DOM has been loaded.So try putting the script tag at the bottom of page

Answer (score 3):

Your file is probably being executed before the DOM has finished loading so the element with that id does not exist yet. All DOM interactions that are not the result of a user event (like click) should be called in a block like:

```
window.addEvent('load',function(){
  // Your code here
});
```

or if you use JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Your code here 
});
```

Comment: <head> <script type='text/javascript' src='index.js'></script> 
 </head>

HTML: <p id = "changetext"> Unlock the universe of JavaScript </p>

window.addEvent('load',function(){
  docs = document.getElementById('changetext');
 alert(docs.innerHTML);
    docs.innerHTML = "Welcome to JavaScript Universe";
});


Still not working.